# How do I prevent the user from clicking on a link on another site inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am loading other web site result into my website page in iframe.

I want to restrict visitors so they are not able to access that site content further in my website iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a transparent image overtop that iFrame which will capture the clicks.

Comment: +1 Obviously not fool-proof, but this is a simple answer that will do what the user wants... and because there is no security implications in having the user "break" this hack, it's all he needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are relying on a simple IFrame code, you cannot control the other site.

One approach to solve your problem is to write a server side code that will read the target page, and strip out all the link or only show the necessary info. (This technique is called [Web Scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)).

Another alternative is to investigate if result web site can provide data to you via XML, JSON, or RSS feed.  This will give you more control on your web content.

Comment: This will work, but it's more complicated than Erick's answer, and could run into problems if external js/css files aren't loadable from remote sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can not control the user in another domain. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents it.